# NVME Samsung SSD 970 EVO (500GB) wrong SMART Power On Hours?

Tags: 18.04, samsung, smart, nvme

I was taking a look to the SMART report of the system disk of one of the servers when I noticed a lower amount of `Power On Hours` than I might have expected.

```
#> sudo smartctl -a /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Samsung_SSD_970_EVO_500GB_S466NX0KB88026N
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-44-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB
Serial Number:                      S466NX0KB88026N
Firmware Version:                   2B2QEXE7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 500,107,862,016 [500 GB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      4
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          500,107,862,016 [500 GB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            287,812,485,120 [287 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 5b81b2c6fe
Local Time is:                      Fri May 31 10:50:46 2019 CEST
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     6.20W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.30W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     2.10W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0400W       -        -    3  3  3  3      210    1200
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2000    8000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        37 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    2,078,942 [1.06 TB]
Data Units Written:                 7,888,803 [4.03 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 8,436,608
Host Write Commands:                252,956,650
Controller Busy Time:               241
Power Cycles:                       54
Power On Hours:                     775
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   24
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      3
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               37 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               40 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 64 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

The server is up 24/7 since months (Ubuntu 18.04 amd64 with `smartmontools` at version `7.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1`), but doing the math (775/24) it looks like the disk is on since 32 days.

In fact, `uptime` says the server is being up for 3 months.

```
#> uptime
 10:33:44 up 100 days, 11:56,  1 user,  load average: 0.35, 0.14, 0.08
```

Is this counter broken, am I reading it wrong or a third hypothesis?

(Not only for their lower reliability, but another reason why I stopped buying Seagate disks is because I can't read their SMART reports "with the naked eye".)

Comment: Mine is also not very "smart" in displaying these statistics. I suppose that each disk is very different on how these counters should be interpreted. You may have to use the tool provided by the disk manufacturer. However, as in my case, the manufacturers of many disks **do not provide tools for Linux**.

Comment: Yes, exactly... So I suppose that we should try to blame `smartmontools` here...

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, 970 EVOs report their power on hours in 8ths of an hour instead, so multiply by 8 to get the true value. This is true for me using both smartmontools and CrystalDiskInfo on Windows.

I took readings from a 1TB 970 EVO Plus. At timestamp 1674634233 it reported 585 hours, and at timestamp 1675031309 it reported 599. Multiplying by 8 puts it at just about 200 days powered on, which is correct for when I installed it.

Comment: Terrible if true. Why should an hard drive keep numbers/8? To save storage?

Comment: @Avio, I don't know why, but I just set up a script to log the power on hours regularly, and reviewing the output for the last 24 hours shows that the Power On Hours for the Samsung 970 does in fact tick once every 8 hours. Goofy, but definitely happening. Anyone know if this is industry standard? I suspect it is, but I don't have the ability to check with a different NVME drive just now.